# Detecting when macOS 10.14 accent color has changed

Tags: objective-c, macos, nscolor

In macOS 10.14 you can detect when the system theme has changed by listening to the following notification:

```
[NSDistributedNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver: self
                                                  selector: @selector(OSThemeChanged:)
                                                      name: @"AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification"
                                                    object: nil];
```

But this does not get fired when the `Accent color` changes ([NSColor.controlAccentColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/3000782-controlaccentcolor?language=objc)). I have an image I want to modify based on the accent color, so I would like to know when it changes.

Has anyone been able to figure this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AppleColorPreferencesChangedNotification` key should work I believe:

```
    [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                        selector:@selector(accentColorChanged:)
                                                            name:@"AppleColorPreferencesChangedNotification"
                                                          object:nil];
```

Notification isn't sent until the preference is changed and the system preferences general window is closed.

Couldn't find the documentation to link to for it though.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thank you. In additional I had found another workaround where `drawRect:` is being called when the `accentColor` is changed. By storing the accentColor details, then comparing it to the current accentColor details I was also able to detect the change (and without waiting for the preference window to be closed either).

Comment: May I ask how did you figure that Notification name out? :) It's working flawlessly. it's only that it is nowhere in the official documentation so I wonder it may disappear in the future without any warning.